# Send large amount of emails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project where an administrator should be able to send about 200 mails in one go to users (no, it's not spam - it's a service, I promise! ;-))

I've been searching for a solution to this as I don't want to go `client.Send();` in a for loop since that could cause problems with mails not being sent. The answers I've read suggests that we should use a new thread for sending mails and I've come up with the following helper method for sending mails:

```
public static void SendEmails(string fromEmail, string subject, string bodyText, List<Customer> recepients)
{
    try
    {
        // Loop through recepients and create a new mail message
        foreach (var recepient in recepients)
        {
            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            message.To.Add(recepient.Email);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = bodyText;                    

            // Send the email async to avoid blocking the main thread
            var client = new SmtpClient();
            client.SendCompleted += (se, ea) =>
            {
                client.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();
            };

            client.SendAsync(message, null);
        }

    }
    catch
    {                

    }
}
```

And my REST API controller looks like this:

```
public bool SendMail(EmailRequest request)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (MemberHelper.IsLoggedIn() && MemberHelper.IsAdmin())
    {

        // Send emails
        if (request.Customers != null)
        {
            MailHelper.SendEmails("my@email.com", request.EmailSubject, request.EmailBodyText, request.Customers);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I make a call to the SenMail rest method, I get this exception:

```
An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer per se but you might want to look at the asynch/await keywords introduced in c# 5 they make it easier to work with aynch operations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: Is there a reason you can't send a single email with all the recipients listed in the BCC field?

Comment: If you send a single mail to multiple recipients you move the burden of distributing the mail from your service to the mail server. And you can use BCC to hide the recipients.

Comment: Alright, so basically send one mail with the first recepients email as the "To" email and then the rest added to the BCC collection? :-) For some reason I thought that was quite a dirty way of doing it, but I might aswell be (very) wrong ;-)

Comment: Usually you would put *all* your recipients in BCC, this way nobody sees the e-mail address the mail has been sent to.

Also, be careful with that kind of things, depending on the SMTP server you're using, it can very easily flag you as a "spammer" and ban you from sending mails. If you send to Gmail or Outlook online and they detect you sent a lot of mail in a short amount of time they also can flag you.

There are services that exist for this purpose, like MailGun for example.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gimly. So what about the "To" mail address? Should that just be some dummy address, or? :-) I'll take note of the SMTP flagging as I'm not entirely sure which SMTP server we're going to use. Thanks!

Comment: @BoMortensen send it to yourself (or your sender address) in the To field. That way you know for sure it's been sent.